# Error during installation of SiLabs 2102 VCP driver on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave, usbserial

I'm having trouble installing the Version 6 of the "CP210x Macintosh OS VCP Driver v6" on my mac OS Mojave.

The error is "unexpected reply from installKextFromBundle kOSKextReturnNotLoadable (-603946989) at -[AppDelegate takeInstallStep]_block_invoke_10:1290"

I have disabled the SIP on the mac, and trying to install this driver so that I can use the ESPxx family microcontrollers using the Arduino IDE.

I must have tried multiple times trying to install/ uninstall and have been unsuccessful so far.

[image]

The MacOS version is :

[image]

The installer is :

[image]

The USB interface is :

[image]

The only driver that is installed is :

$ ls -l /dev/cu*
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   1 Dec  8 18:54 /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port

Would appreciate if there is some one who can tell how to remove / clean up and install this driver clean.

Have run the ./uninstaller.sh multiple times, rebooted it and such.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I received the same errors but I've successfully installed. I used Homebrew to `brew install --cask silicon-labs-vcp-driver` and the cask requires manually running the installer. I had Fast User Switching active and was logged-in with another admin user at the time. I found, after several failed install attempts on the first admin user's account, that the System Preferences authorisation pane was also displayed on the *second* admin user's account. I authorised and logged-out of the second user's account, then attempted to install from the `.dmg` I'd downloaded directly from https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers. That finally succeeded.